# How can I simulate and measure brute force hacking using RSA?

Tags: rsa, post-quantum-cryptography, security-definition

I want to implement brute force hacking using RSA. How can I simulate and measure time duration? What software (or software-based simulator) would be needed?

Comment: First, you shoudl specify, what you actually want to brute-force. Is it factoring $n$, or finding $d$, or finding $m$ to a certain ciphertext $c$? Anyway, brute force in general is a bad idea here, since the "try out everything" approach has a MUCH higher complexity than factoring with the [GNFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) (very rough approximation: $2^{n}$ vs $2^{n/3}$)

Comment: Maybe you meant RSA hacking using brute force?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I assume we are talking about classical computers

Implementing a brute force attack on a RSA may not be the most sensible thing, unless of course the security parameter of your target system is small.. (160 bit numbers! )

Even then you may not want to implement a brute force here.. try using Fermat's Factoring or  Pollards $\rho$ method.

If you just want to measure time try to do a more theoretical research, i.e. use the time take per multiplication op. and the no. of operations your computer can perform in a sec to determine exactly how long will it take you to brute force a $n-$bit security.

To sum it up, YOU CANNOT BRUTE FORCE THE (properly implemented) MODERN DAY RSA (~4096 bit numbers) even if you use all computers in your state.

Comment: Did you mean 160 digits (about 530 bits) rather than 160 bit? That's more like the limit of brute-forcing RSA for an individual.

Comment: 160 bits sound about right if by "brute force" one means literally iterating through all odd numbers from $\sqrt(N)$ and checking if the value divides $N$.

Comment: @fgrieu 530 bit is in the ballpark of brute force, however, it will take some time (months) to do that with a modern day PC (I assume the asker does not have access to supercomputers or clusters).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean simulate, but if you need a toy example in python the code is at the end of the message.
If you need to show the performance of more advanced algorithms use `factor(x)` in pari/gp. See [here](http://mvngu.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/parigp-programming-for-basic-cryptography/) for details.

```
import gmpy, time, random, math

def genprime(bits):
    p=1
    while(gmpy.is_prime(p)==0):
        p = random.randrange(math.pow(2,bits-1),math.pow(2,bits))
    return p

BITS=20
found=False
p=genprime(BITS)
q=genprime(BITS)
n=p*q
cnt=2
s_time=time.time()
while not found:
    found=(n%cnt==0)
    cnt+=1
e_time=time.time()-s_time
if found:
    print "%d can be devided by %d"%(n, cnt-1)
    print "It took %d ms "%(cnt-1)
```